# Custom EnvOptions location

Tags: delphi, msbuild

Is there a way to override EnvOptions.proj location or at least to disable it's searching by Delphi compiler when building a project from command line using msbuild?

Comment: OK, it seems that `/p:EnvOptionsWarn=false` and `ImportEnvOptions=false` partially solved "default" loading and the project compiles fine without any warnings. But overriding it with a custom path like `/p:EnvOptions=c:/temp/EnvOptions.proj` give `error F1027: Unit not found: 'System'`. Some ideas took from `CodeGear.Common.Targets` file. Any other toughts?

Comment: I haven't played with command line compiler but I'm guessing that the problem relies in the fact that you only provided one folder for your environment options while Delphi require more. You see you also need to pas paths to all other needed folders that contain Delphi units.

Comment: @SilverWarior, `EnvOptions.proj` contains itself multiple paths like Library Path, etc...

Comment: Curioius, how did you solve this issue?  I am just copying from my dev box to my build server